# rails route constraint based on param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, rails-routing

I am trying to setup a route only used on development that matches everything except routes that have `/attachments/` in the url. Is this possible?

Example:

```
  match '*a', to: 'errors#four_oh_four', via: :all, constraints: { all: /^(?!.*attachments).*$/ } if Rails.env.development?
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few posts I came across here is how I solved this:

```
  match '*a', to: 'errors#four_oh_four', via: :all, constraints: ->(req) { !req.env['REQUEST_PATH'].include?('attachments') } if Rails.env.development?
```

Passes Rubocops: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
Guide found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7924